# Get coordinate of new rectangle with Matlab's imrect

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For my project, I have a lot of pictures that I need to extract a ROI. When my project starts, I want a picture to show and then the user to select the ROI that he/she wants. The function `imrect` seems to be doing that. I am trying to get the coordinate of the rectangle, once it has been dragged or resized. The problem is that the values returned do not seem to be correct.

I can't seem to find the problem and the related questions didn't help. I tried using `imcrop`, but couldn't do any better...

```
function [ new_image ] = getRoi(image)

rect = size(image);
rect = round(rect ./2);

figure, imshow(image);

h = imrect(gca, [5 5 rect(2) rect(1)]);

addNewPositionCallback(h,@(p) title(mat2str(p,3)));
fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect',get(gca,'XLim'),get(gca,'YLim'));
accepted_pos = wait(h);
setPositionConstraintFcn(h,fcn);
%getPositionConstraintFcn(h);

pos = getPosition(h);

if round(pos(1)) < round(pos(2))
    X1 = round(pos(1))
    X2 = round(pos(2))
else
    X1 = round(pos(2))
    X2 = round(pos(1))
end

if round(pos(3)) < round(pos(4))
    Y1 = round(pos(3))
    Y2 = round(pos(4))
else
    Y1 = round(pos(4))
    Y2 = round(pos(3))
end

new_image = image(Y1:Y2, X1:X2);

%name = strcat('Roi_', datestr(clock, 'yyyymmddTHHMMSS'),'.png');
%prtIm(new_image, name, '-s');
new_image = image;

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getPosition` returns `[xmin, ymin, width, height]`. To get the coordinates you want, try

```
X1 = round(pos(1));
Y1 = round(pos(2));
X2 = round(X1 + pos(3));
Y2 = round(Y1 + pos(4));
```

Comment: I think you meant Y2 = round(Y1 + pos(4));   And, by the way, THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!